# Why doesn'T my JOIN mysql work?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, mysqli

So i need information from 2 Tables, but my JOIN Mysqli just won't work, can anybody tell me whats the problem? :/ 
I'm new to INNER JOIN's so it could be I understand something wrong x_x

```
 if($stream = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT $title.message_id, $title.message, $title.likes, $title.dislikes, $title.poster, $title.date, $title.closed user.rank, user.posts, user.reputation FROM  $title INNER JOIN User ON $title.poster = user.username ORDER BY message_id ASC")){
                                    $stream->execute();
                                        $stream->bind_result($message_id, $message, $likes, $dislikes, $poster, $date, $closed, $rank, $posts, $rep, $usnm);

                                        while($stream->fetch()){
```

Comment: What "won't work"? Not the results you want? An Error?

Comment: Do $title contain the name of the table ? If so, check if it is set to the correct value.

Comment: $title = $_GET["title"]; 
so yeah its set

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you sure that `$title` is defined ? Are you sure that `user` have uppercase ?

```
SELECT *
FROM $title
INNER JOIN user
ON $title.poster = user.username
ORDER BY message_id ASC;
```

Comment: But how will my

 $stream->bind_result($message_id, $message, $likes, $dislikes, $poster, $date, $closed, $rank, $posts, $rep, $usnm);

will look like with that?

Also yes, $title is defined, above the part it says 
 $title = $_GET["title"];

Comment: So I guess i need to find out what Variables I need..



    if($stream = $mysqli->prepare("
             SELECT *
             FROM $title
             INNER JOIN User
             ON $title.poster = User.username
             ORDER BY message_id ASC;
                  ")){
           $stream->execute();
           
           $stream->bind_result($message_id, $message, $likes, $dislikes, $poster, $date, $closed, $user_id, $username, $password, $rank, $age, $sex, $name, $website, $skype, $email. $last_act, $posts, $reputation, $credits, $reg_date);

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you're missing a comma between columns: `$title.closed<needs comma here> user.rank`

Answer (score 0):

First you have a missing coma here:

```
$title.closed user.rank
```

And, inside your query the table "user" should be used as "User" with a capital letter as declared in the inner join. And the inner join is wrong.

You should always begin the inner join condition by the joined table :

WRONG

```
FROM  $title INNER JOIN User ON $title.poster = user.username
```

GOOD

```
FROM  $title INNER JOIN User ON User.username = $title.poster
```

Comment: please post the full query without php variable with carriage return so it will be more clear for us to help you. thank you.